# Creating a tenure column in Days in R

Tags: r, date, days

I am trying to create a column in a df that shows me the day number in a client's tenure. Here is the code to create a mock df for this:-

```
     Date<-c("20/07/2018", "21/07/2018", "25/07/2018", "02/08/2018", "05/08/2018", "10/08/2018")
     ClientId<-c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
     EventId<-c("klk109", "rrt234", "hjk786", "yyu777", "tyw909", "nnl991")
     dateclient<-cbind(Date, ClientId)
     LoginDates<-cbind(dateclient, EventId)
     View(LoginDates)
```

which should give you something like this:-

```
   head(LoginDates)

      Date     ClientId  EventId 
  "20/07/2018" "aaa"    "klk109"
  "21/07/2018" "bbb"    "rrt234"
  "25/07/2018" "ccc"    "hjk786"
  "02/08/2018" "aaa"    "yyu777"
  "05/08/2018" "bbb"    "tyw909"
  "10/08/2018" "ccc"    "nnl991"
```

Essentialy, I want to create a column to add onto the end like this

```
     Date    ClientId  EventId   tenureDay
 "20/07/2018" "aaa"    "klk109"      1
 "21/07/2018" "bbb"    "rrt234"      1
 "25/07/2018" "ccc"    "hjk786"      1
 "02/08/2018" "aaa"    "yyu777"     13
 "05/08/2018" "bbb"    "tyw909"     15
 "10/08/2018" "ccc"    "nnl991"     16
```

However, my main issue in my dataset (the above being a mock df), some Clients have had more than one interaction per day (some have had 10, 20 and so on). The code I wrote (a "for" loop and some data.table code) has returned the number of interactions (or EventIds), and not the day number in tenure.   If a client has been in the service for 10 days and has had, say 4 interactions during that time, I want the tenureDay column to represent the day in their tenure that particular interaction took place on.

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong, so you want to find the day difference between the first Date and the rest of the Date column? So that you can see how many days have passed since that client acquired tenure?

Comment: Hi Maylo. What I want is to create a column which tells he the day number in tenure i.e. "Day 1", "Day 2" etc. For example: if a client is in the service between 01/01/2018 and their last date was 01/06/2018, then they have been in the service for for 151 days. If that client logs into the service, for example, the 20/05/2018, I want the tenure column to say "139" as that is the 139 day of that client's tenure. I hope this clarifies things!

Comment: And I assume that the tenure start date is the first date that appears in the table?

Comment: sorry I have made an error in asking my question, I shall update this now. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: @Maylo please refer to the question now, I have amended it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for amending the question!

For reproductivity:

```
LoginDates <- fread("Date     ClientId  EventId 
                    2018-07-20 aaa    klk109
                    2018-07-21 bbb    rrt234
                    2018-07-25 ccc    hjk786
                    2018-08-02 aaa    yyu777
                    2018-08-05 bbb    tyw909
                    2018-08-10 ccc    nnl991")
```

Using `dplyr`, you could try this:

```
LoginDates %>%
  group_by(ClientId) %>%
  mutate(tenureDay = as.Date(Date) - head(as.Date(Date),1))
```

I really hope this solves your problem!

**EDIT:**

If you do not want your result to appear like `x Days` then try:

```
LoginDates %>%
  group_by(ClientId) %>%
  mutate(tenureDay = as.numeric(as.Date(Date) - head(as.Date(Date),1)))
```

Comment: Hi @Maylo, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately its not really working as intended to in this case. Is there any other methods that come to mind?

Comment: Is there a way if I want the tenure in terms of Months (instead of Days)?