# Calculating Tenure Day in R

Tags: r, date, days

So I had asked a similar question a while ago (see [Creating a tenure column in Days in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987644/creating-a-tenure-column-in-days-in-r)) but I wasn't able to achieve the right result, but now I have worked another possible way to ask for the same thing, which may be a bit easier to work out.

The problem: I am looking to create a column which tells me the day of client tenure. Here is some mock code:

```
    Date<-c("01/01/2018", "12/02/2018", "10/03/2018", "22/03/2018", "29/03/2018", "01/04/2018", "02/04/2018","04/04/2018","07/04/2018","11/04/2018", "15/04/2018", "17/04/2018","19/04/2018","21/04/2018","22/04/2018", "29/04/2018", "01/05/2018","03/05/2018","08/05/2018", "10/05/2018", "12/05/2018")
    ClientID<-c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg","aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg","aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg")
    df<-cbind(ClientID, Date)
    df<-as.data.frame(df)
    df$Date<-dmy(df$Date)
    df$yearDay<-df$Date
    df$yearDay<-yday(df$yearDay)
```

Giving you something like this:

```
    df

   ClientID       Date      yearDay
   aaa          2018-01-01       1
   bbb          2018-02-12      43
   ccc          2018-03-10      69
   ddd          2018-03-22      81
   eee          2018-03-29      88
   fff          2018-04-01      91
   ggg          2018-04-02      92
   aaa          2018-04-04      94
   bbb          2018-04-07      97
   ccc          2018-04-11     101
   ddd          2018-04-15     105
   eee          2018-04-17     107
   fff          2018-04-19     109
   ggg          2018-04-21     111
   aaa          2018-04-22     112
   bbb          2018-04-29     119
   ccc          2018-05-01     121
   ddd          2018-05-03     123
   eee          2018-05-08     128
   fff          2018-05-10     130
   ggg          2018-05-12     132
```

Now what I want to do (but not sure how to do it) is to take the yearDay number in second instance for each Client ID, and subtract the yearDay in the previous instance. Then take the yearDay number in the third instance and subtract the yearDay in the previous instance. And so on and so forth (I have over four million rows of data). The answer should leave me with the tenure day. Looking like this:-

```
    ClientID       Date      yearDay     tenureDay
    aaa          2018-01-01       1          1
    bbb          2018-02-12      43          1
    ccc          2018-03-10      69          1
    ddd          2018-03-22      81          1
    eee          2018-03-29      88          1 
    fff          2018-04-01      91          1
    ggg          2018-04-02      92          1
    aaa          2018-04-04      94          93 
    bbb          2018-04-07      97          54
    ccc          2018-04-11     101          48
    ddd          2018-04-15     105          24
    eee          2018-04-17     107          19
    fff          2018-04-19     109          18
    ggg          2018-04-21     111          19
```

Any idea as to how I would achieve this?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `mutate()`, `arrange()`, `lag()`, and `group_by()` from the `dplyr` package for this.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ClientID) %>%
  arrange(yearDay) %>%
  mutate(tenureDay = yearDay - lag(yearDay))
```